# How to login as oracle home user to oracleDB?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

Is there any way to login as oracle home user to the OracleDB?
I created a Oracle home user during installation.

[image]

If not then what is this home user account used for? Can there be multiple Oracle home user account and How?

This is what I am  getting currently,

[image]

Comment: What is that windows user account used for in Oracle

Comment: Using another administrator account

Comment: OS version : Windows R2 datacenter, Oracle version : 19c, during installation of oracle I created OS user admin(screenshot) from which I am trying to login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe "oracle home user" is an *operating system* account, used for installing oracle, and it owns the installed files/directories.  It is *not* an account within the database, and so there is no such concept of logging on to the *database* as "the oracle home user".

Exactly what are you trying to achieve?  Why do you think you want to connect to the database "as the oracle home user"?